# PHP "If true" test on array always returns true?

Tags: php, arrays, return, boolean

I have a validation function that I want to return true if the validation passes, or an array of errors if validation fails.  However, when I check if the function returns true, it returns true even if the returned value is an array.  Why is this?  As a further example of what I mean:

```
$array = ['test' => 'test'];
if ($array == true)
  {
  echo 'true';
  }
```

and I also tried the same with a string:

```
$string = 'string';
if ($string == true)
  {
  echo 'true';
  }
```

And both echo true.

Why is this?  And if we can do this then why do we need the isset() function?

Comment: you can use `count()` for array, if it is 0 then it is false

Comment: I know these are options - I want to know why it returns true if it isn't "true"?  And why do we need the isset function if we can just use if ($variable)?

Comment: I assume this is just expected behaviour?  But it seems so counter intuitive, and I'm amazed I've not come across this before :/

Comment: if($array === true) check the typeof too

Comment: There are several answers in stackoverflow regarding this question and also on php doc.

Comment: isset() will check variable exist or not and if($variable) will check $variable value is not 0 or false.

Comment: declared `$variables` or empty string will return true. unless you declare your `$variables` as false.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy and Ruchish, this is what I needed :)

Comment: [PHP type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: welcome then give up vote to comment. :D @user3640967

Comment: I have done now.  Thanks everyone.  I wish all my questions had this many replies this quickly!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior as documented in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

```
Expression             gettype()  empty()   is_null()   isset() boolean
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
$x = array();          array      TRUE      FALSE       TRUE    FALSE
$x = array('a', 'b');  array      FALSE     FALSE       TRUE    TRUE
$x = "";               string     TRUE      FALSE       TRUE    FALSE
$x = "php";            string     FALSE     FALSE       TRUE    TRUE
```

So an empty string or array will evaluate to `false` and non empty strings or arrays will evaluate to `true`.

On the other hand `isset()` will determine if a variable is defined regardless of it's actual value. The only value being somehow different is `null`. A variable with value `null` will return false if tested with `isset()`.